# Multiple updating state which is an object in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

How should I update properties of some object in state if I don't know exactly which properties I want to update? I get these properties from the arguments of a function, and argument is an array of keys I want to update. Here is what I try to do, but 2nd `updateObj()` call overwrites changes (but I want that changes should merge):

```
let newObj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
}

let [obj, setObj] = React.useState(newObj)

function updateObj(keys, values) {
    let key, newProps = [], updatedValues = {}
    for (let k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
        key = keys[k]
        newProps.push(obj[key] + values[k])
    }

    keys.forEach((key, index) => {
        updatedValues[key] = newProps[index]
    })

    setObj(prevState => {
        return {...prevState, ...updatedValues}
    })
}

function changeState() {
    updateObj(['a', 'c'], [1, 1])//add 1 to a and 1 to c
    updateObj(['a', 'b', 'c'], [-1, 1, -1])//add -1 to a, 1 to b and 1 to c
    //in the end i want to get {a: 1, b: 3, c: 3}
}

React.useEffect(() => {console.log(obj)}, [obj])

return (
    <someComponent onMouseDown={()=>changeState()}/>//state updating here
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to create a new object based on `prevState`:

```
function updateObj(keys, values) {
  setObj(prevState => 
    keys.reduce((acc, key, index) => ({
      ...acc,
      [key]: acc[key] + values[index]
    }), prevState)
  )
}
```

Another option is create a new object from `keys` and `values` and then merge the two objects:

```
function updateObj(keys, values) {
  setObj(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    ...Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, index) => 
      [key, values[index]]
    )
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would calculate it first and then swap the state object

```
function updateObj(keys, values) {
  setObj((prevState) => {
    const newState = { ...prevState };
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
      newState[keys[i]] += values[i];
    }
    return newState;
  });
}
```

Comment: thats not the issue, because in theory i want to call state updates in random places, but anyway thanks for answer